# Displaying React component on same line as other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to get a React component I've built to display on the same line as the rest of the text, but it keeps appearing on a different line than the rest of the elements.

Here's my React code:

```
<div className={styles['top']}>
    <span>WHAT PEOPLE ARE SAYING</span>
    <div className={`pull-right ${styles['right']}`}>
      <span className={`${styles['rating-words']}`}>{ratingWords}</span>
      <Rating className={`${styles['overall-stars']}`}
              percentage={this.state.overallPercentage}
              color={"#00c18a"}
              under={"white"}
      />

    </div>
  </div>
```

and the .scss:

```
.top {
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  .right {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .rating-words {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

and finally, a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Both "VERY GOOD" and the rating stars should be on the same line. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does the outputted HTML look like? I think this is more related to the HTML+CSS than it is to React.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two child elements inside of .top this should work.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcLcsoag/1/)

```
.top {
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .rating-words {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .right {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up getting it to work with the following based on what @Chad said though what @torkjels said ended up working better in another place.

```
.top {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  .right {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .rating-words {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .overall-stars {
    margin-top: -2px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you post a working jsfiddle or codepen it would be easier to help.

Try giving your `overall-stars` class `display: inline-block`. I assume it's already a block element, which makes it appear on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
const top = {
    // Other styles
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
}
```

Might help.